Animation on roblox problems
My friend used the script on Roblox Studio:




local cas = game:GetService("ContextActionService")
local rs = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

local events = rs:WaitForChild("Events")
local hitboxEvent = events:WaitForChild("Hitbox")

local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character = plr.Character or plr.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local hum = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local animator = hum:WaitForChild("Animator")

local rightPunch = animator:LoadAnimation(script:WaitForChild("RightPunch"))

local currentPunch = 0

local debounce = false
local function punch()
    if debounce then return end
    debounce = true
    if currentPunch == 0 then
        rightPunch:Play()
        hitboxEvent:FireServer(Vector3.new(1,1,1), Vector3.new(

5), 50, 0.3)
        task.wait(0.4)
        debounce = false
    elseif currentPunch == 1 then
        rightPunch:Play()
        hitboxEvent:FireServer(Vector3.new(1,1,1), Vector3.new(2,5), 50, 0.3)
        debounce = false
    elseif currentPunch == 2 then
        rightPunch:Play()
        hitboxEvent:FireServer(Vector3.new(1,1,1), Vector3.new(2,5), 50, 0.3)
        debounce = false
    end
    
    if currentPunch == 2 then
        currentPunch = 0
    else
        currentPunch += 1   
    end
end

cas:BindAction("Punch", punch, true, Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1)
Screenshot
The script is running perfectly for him, but not for me. The animation will not play on my game but it works on his screen. He was the one who made the animation, but it also works for my other friend. How do I fix this? (Computer: Mac, Apple M3, macOS Sonoma V.14.6.1)
I cleared Roblox studio's cache. I expected it to work. it did not. (By the way, do NOT use solutions that turn off my firewall)
